# Error Call for get JSON Function Within For Loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, getjson

I'm having a problem reformatting my JavaScript by removing a function that I have from within a loop.

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //GET TWITCH TV STREAMERS' STATUS AND API CALL

  var twitchTvStreamers = ["FreeCodeCamp", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

  //OUT OF ALL THE TWITCH TV STREAMERS IN A TWITCH TV ARRAY FIND THOSE 8 STREAMERS LISTED
  for (var i = 0; i < twitchTvStreamers.length; i++) {

    //DO A GETJSON ON THIS ARRAY TO RETRIEVE INFORMATION FROM THE VALUES OF THOSE 8 TWITCH TV STREAMERS
    $.getjSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams' + val, function (st) {
      //var url="https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams" 

      channelName = val;

      //IF ANY OF THE STATUSES OF THE 8 TWITCH TV STREAMERS ARE EQUAL TO NULL, OR OFFLINE, THEN DO SOMETHING
      if (st.stream === null) {
        //GET JSON INFO OF THOSE OFFLINE STREAMERS
        $.getjSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels' + val, function (ch) {

          channelID = ch.Display_name;
          channelLogo = ch.logo;
          channelUrl = ch.url;
          streamContent = ch.content;

          //POST INFO TO DISPLAY AREA OF WEB APP (...ADD OTHER STUFF TO THIS APPEND LATER)
          $('#offline').append('<div class="TV-screen">');
        });

      } else
        //REPEAT SAME SCENARIO AS USED FOR OFFLINE STREAM STATUS    
        $.getjSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels' + val, function (ch) {

          channelID = ch.Display_name;
          channelLogo = ch.logo;
          channelUrl = ch.url;
          streamContent = ch.content;

          $('#online').append('<div class="TV-screen">');
        });

    }
```

//with help from: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nm2bXBlELZU&list=PLHdCowjFIBmJwYL9tPZOkn6CIVLg6Z36a, etc. etc......

I placed the above code into [www.jshint.com](http://jshint.com/) and it gave the following results:

Three warnings":

1. 11  Don't make functions within a loop.
2. 42  Expected ')' and instead saw ''.
3. 49  Unrecoverable syntax error. (100% scanned).

How can I reformat my code (at line 11) to include my get JSON function, but without it being within the loop?

Comment: Where does `val` come from?

Comment: @Phil, `channelName = val;`

Comment: that doesn't answer my question at all

Comment: @Phil, val comes out of the get JSON API call

Comment: No it doesn't. You're even using it in the URL and it's not defined anywhere. I suspect you want `var val = twitchTvStreamers[i]` but who knows. Even if you fix this you're going to run into all sorts of issues using a callback function within a `for` loop

Comment: @Phil, this is an excerpt from which I got this .......
         `$.each(channelList, function (i, val) {
           $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.gomix.me/twitch-api/streams/' + val, function (st) {
               channelName = val;`

I'm trying to rennovate the code in my own way, without pure jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a large number of errors in syntax, typos, wrong function names and wrong usage of the placeholders for deferred returns of the asynch calls. A summary of the errors is below. Meanwhile, run the code to make sure that it actually works.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
// Who we want to stalk today
var twitchTvStreamers=["FreeCodeCamp", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

// Get the status of each channel using the getChannelInfo() function
for(channel of twitchTvStreamers){
    getChannelInfo(channel);
    }
});

// This function gets the status of each channel
// and, depending whether it is online or offline, 
// calls the appendInfo() function with the online/offline parameter
var getChannelInfo = channel => { 
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + channel)
    .done(function(info) {
        if (info.stream === null) appendInfo(channel,'offline');
        else appendInfo(channel,'online');
    });
}

// This function gets info on whether the channel is online or offline. 
// Depending on this status, it gets the channel info 
// and appends it in the respective `<div>`
var appendInfo = (channel,target) => {
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/' + channel)
        .done( function(ch){
            channelID = ch.display_name;
            channelLogo = ch.logo;
            channelUrl = ch.url;
            streamContent = ch.content;
            $('#'+target).append('<div class="TV-screen">'+channel+' is '+target);
        });    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="online"></div>
<div id="offline"></div>
```

So, your problems with the code were:

1. `channel = val;` sets the channel variable, not the val variable. `val = channel` would set the val variable but that wouldn't work in your code either. You could set val like `val = twitchTvStreamers[i];`
2. `getjSON` should be spelled as `getJSON` - case matters!
3. `ch.Display_name` won't work as the returned object key is spelled as `display_name`. Again, be careful with your cases.
4. `$('#offline').append('<div class="TV-screen">');` - this just adds a blank `<div>` to the `#offline` element. You would want to include some of the channel-specifit information here as well.
5. And, most important of all, you gotta understand exactly how [JS Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) works. The last best resource I read on this was Kyle Simpson's [Asynch & Performance](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance) book from his *You don't know JS* series. jQuery's `getJSON` uses the Promise interface, so knowing the underlying technology definitely helps.

In a nutshell - when you are making an [asynch call](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/front-end-javascript/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript), the response takes a while to come through and meanwhile, other code executes. For example, you have a variable called `status`, and you are making an API call for the statuses of Twitch channels *foo* and *bar*. Until the API response comes back, your code already prints out `<div id="foo">` and `<div id="bar">` on the page. Then the statuses come back, status of channel *foo* comes back as *online* and sets the `status` variable as 'online'. Then, status of *bar* comes back as 'offline' and sets `status` variable to offline. And, if not handled properly, JS returns this last value (offline), and it applies to all of your elements.

You have to be able to make the call and promise its result to the correct DOM element. I did it as following:

- Get the status

  - If online, get the channel details, produce a DOM element, append to the 'online' div
  - If offline, get the channel details, produce a DOM element, append to the 'offline' div

Here the sequence of producing and appending DOM elements does not cross the sequence of making AJAX calls and getting the results. It is the easiest to break this sequence down to separate functions and call them by each step, which I did.

Comment: OMG! How the hell did you fix that so fast! Are you a JavaScript expert!?? OMG! WOW! Can you also upvote my question/post, because this is something great for everyone to see, and I need the votes :) Thankyou so much!!!!

Comment: your code is working, but it's giving me this error: **"$ is undefined?"** Is the problem my browser?

Comment: You gotta add jQuery to your page

Comment: that worked! I had it before too...but it wasn't working.....when I added yours it worked lol....thankyou for helping me out.....I have to add some other project requirements to the javascript code.....hopefully it won't messup what you coded lol....also interesting.....why did you use `.done`? .....never seen that property before!

Comment: ES6 only solution. This will not work in all browsers

Comment: OP did not ask for legacy code. And the `ES6` in this code is only its syntax, which can be easily modified if need be. In the worst case - Babel is your friend.

Answer (score -2):

1. You forgot large number of brackets at the end. This is how your code might look like

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {

   //GET TWITCH TV STREAMERS' STATUS AND API CALL

   var twitchTvStreamers = ["FreeCodeCamp", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

   //OUT OF ALL THE TWITCH TV STREAMERS IN A TWITCH TV ARRAY FIND THOSE 8 STREAMERS LISTED
   twitchTvStreamers.map(function(val) {

       //DO A GETJSON ON THIS ARRAY TO RETRIEVE INFORMATION FROM THE VALUES OF THOSE 8 TWITCH TV STREAMERS
       $.getjSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams' + val, function(st) {
           //var url="https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams"  

       channelName = val;

       //IF ANY OF THE STATUSES OF THE 8 TWITCH TV STREAMERS ARE EQUAL TO NULL, OR OFFLINE, THEN DO SOMETHING
       if (st.stream === null) {
           //GET JSON INFO OF THOSE OFFLINE STREAMERS
           $.getjSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels' + val, function(ch) {

               channelID = ch.Display_name;
               channelLogo = ch.logo;
               channelUrl = ch.url;
               streamContent = ch.content;

               //POST INFO TO DISPLAY AREA OF WEB APP (...ADD OTHER STUFF TO THIS APPEND LATER)
               $('#offline').append('<div class="TV-screen">');
           });

       } else {
           //REPEAT SAME SCENARIO AS USED FOR OFFLINE STREAM STATUS    
           $.getjSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels' + val, function(ch) {

               channelID = ch.Display_name;
               channelLogo = ch.logo;
               channelUrl = ch.url;
               streamContent = ch.content;

               $('#online').append('<div class="TV-screen">');

           });
          }
       }); // getJSON
   }); // map
   }); // ready
   ```

this fixes problems 2 and 3. But I'm stiil not sure what is `val` in your code. I guess it's stream name, so I added it to:

2. [array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function instead of `for loop` to avoid 1st problem

Comment: This won't run, there are still heaps of typos and errors in the code.

Comment: @vladkras, yes **val** is stream name, thanks for fixing some of those problems! When I put it into Code Pen it says, **"Unexpected end of input"**

Comment: @vladkras, also the reason why I used `for` loop is because it is faster. I saw an example that used a JQuery `each()` method, but I don't want to use hers [https://codepen.io/Marysh/pen/MJQBYg?editors=1010] ....want to do it my own way...

Comment: @Aydin, I didn't try to fix ALL problems, only those mentioned in jshint as OP asked

Comment: @codebwoy, loop speed means nothing when you have dozens of synchronous ajax request