# Append Info to a Div upon Pressing Button

Tags: javascript, html, button, append

I currently have a Twitch TV web app in which the UI interface is designed in such a way that I want the large blue screen to be where all online and offline info is appended to upon pressing an "all" button, and only online info is appended here when "online" button is pressed, and only offline info is appended when "offline" button is pressed. Currently the info is appended to the wrong divs. How can I fix this?

Here is my codepen:https://codepen.io/IDCoder/pen/mXMqGV?editors=0010

And here is my javascript code:

```
//with help from places..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859596/error-call-for-get-json-function-within-for-loop/48859987#48859987, etc, etc....
$(document).ready(function(){

//GET TWITCH TV STREAMERS' STATUS AND API CALL

var twitchTvStreamers=["FreeCodeCamp", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

//OUT OF ALL THE TWITCH TV STREAMERS IN A TWITCH TV ARRAY FIND THOSE 8 STREAMERS LISTED
for(channel of twitchTvStreamers){
    getChannelInfo(channel);

    }
});
var getChannelInfo = channel => { 
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + channel)
    .done(function(info) {
        if (info.stream === null) appendInfo(channel,'offline');
        else appendInfo(channel,'online');
    });
}
var appendInfo = (channel,target) => {
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/' + channel)
        .done( function(ch){
            channelID = ch.display_name;
            channelLogo = ch.logo;
            channelUrl = ch.url;
            streamContent = ch.content;
            $('#'+target).append('<div class="TV-screen">'+channel+' is '+target);
        });    
}
```

And here is my html code:

```
<html> 

<head>


<title>

</title>

</head> 
<body>

<div class="container">

    <div class="Twitch-TV">
    <h1>Twitch TV Web App</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="share">
      <ul class="soc">
          <li class="declaration">
          SHARE
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-linkedin-square fa-fw"></i>LINKEDIN</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://github.com" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-github fa-fw"></i>GITHUB</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-facebook-official fa-fw"></i>FACEBOOK</a>
          </li>
          <li class="socbutton">
            <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com" target="blank"><i class= "fa fa-fire fa-fw"></i>FREECODECAMP</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="TV-screen"> 
    </div>

    <div class="user-status">
    <button id ="online" type="button" class="online-status" >Online</button>
    <button id ="offline" type="button" class="offline-status" >Offline</button>
    <button id ="all" type="button" class="online-and-offline" >All</button>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" id="searchTerm" placeholder="search streams....">        
    </div>
</div>



</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: you are appending the data to `online` and `offline` div - shouldnt you upload to the `div` with css `TV-screen` instead? something along `$("div .TV-screen")`

Comment: @Jaya, I tried that....let me try again....I also edited my question by providing a snapshot for a quicker preview...

Comment: also you have a div in the HTML with the class name TV-screen then why do you want to append it again as part of your append function?

Comment: @Jaya, this is what's here now `$('#'+target).append('<div class="TV-screen">'+channel+' is '+target);`

Comment: ?. please be a bit clear. you are passing online and offline as the ids to the above statement

Comment: @Jaya, hold on a sec....

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/EQQXBw

Comment: @jaya, yesss! Precisely! Thankyou! And now I want that output that you have on the screen to be only outputted there when you press the all button....online button will out put online info there and the offline button will output only offline info there. As long as no button is pressed, the screen will stay blue.

Comment: Done please check the codepen link: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/EQQXBw

Comment: @Yasir, fantastic! The last part that I want is to have the blue screen stay blank until a button is pressed....so if you refresh the page the blue screen is blank until a button is pressed...caz the idea is to have the screen represent "video blue-screen" as on a TV (changes when a channel is pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Js

```
var twitchTvStreamers;
var loaded = false;
//with help from places..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859596/error-call-for-get-json-function-within-for-loop/48859987#48859987, etc, etc....
$(document).ready(function(){

//GET TWITCH TV STREAMERS' STATUS AND API CALL

twitchTvStreamers=["FreeCodeCamp", "ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];

//OUT OF ALL THE TWITCH TV STREAMERS IN A TWITCH TV ARRAY FIND THOSE 8 STREAMERS LISTED

});

//filter online offline and all
var filterchannel = filterch => { 
  if(!loaded)
  {
    for(channel of twitchTvStreamers){
      getChannelInfo(channel, filterch);
    }
  }
  else
    {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.TV-screen div').each(function(idx, item) {
          if($(item).hasClass(filterch))
            {
              $(item).show();
            }
          else
            {
              $(item).hide();
            }
        });
      }, 100);
    }
};

$('button').click(function(e) {
 filterchannel(e.target.id);
})

var getChannelInfo = (channel, filterch) => { 
    loaded = true;
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/streams/' + channel)
    .done(function(info) {
        console.log(channel);
        if (info.stream === null) {
          appendInfo(channel,'offline',filterch);
        }
        else {
          appendInfo(channel,'online', filterch);
        }

    });
}
var appendInfo = (channel,target, filterch) => {
    $.getJSON('https://wind-bow.glitch.me/twitch-api/channels/' + channel)
        .done( function(ch){
            channelID = ch.display_name;
            channelLogo = ch.logo;
            channelUrl = ch.url;
            streamContent = ch.content;
            $('.TV-screen').append('<div class="' + target + ' all">'+channel+' is '+target);
            if(twitchTvStreamers[twitchTvStreamers.length - 1] === channel) {
              filterchannel(filterch);
            }
        });    
}
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/YasirKamdar/pen/EQQXBw

Comment: you sir are a javascript genius! Thanks so much for your help to a javascript newbie! So much to learn!

Comment: Done, have a look